# Files are read-only after copying over samba

Tags: samba, file-sharing, chmod

I used to copy files from one system to another system via samba. How ever I am getting the file only in read only mode. What i am doing now is i used to change the file permission after transferring the file. It seems to be little time consuming one. Is there any permanent solution to this problem?

[image: Files are read-only after copying over samba]

Still i have the same problem. Pls have a look @ my samba setup.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/614067/

Output:

```
karthick@karthick:~$ groups            
karthick adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Comment: Did you remove the comments from smb.conf? Mine is full of commented instructions? Why is your create mask still set at 0700? Please read my answer on setting permissions for create mask (and no it is unlikely your remote user is the owner of these files but is either part of a 'group' or is 'others'.

Comment: What should be the value for create mask ?

Comment: Easiest answer? 0755. More secure might be 0750 but that would assume both your local and remote user are part of the same group (type `groups` on command line to see what group you are part).

Comment: Updated my question with required outputs, pls look at it. And what is the value i should set it for directory mask ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Configure `create mask` and `directory mask` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with the desired permissions.

from `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700
```

If you need more information there is a [man page on smb.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/smb.conf.5.html).

Regarding the values for the masking:

Permissions 700 means:

```
                 : The 1st octet are permissions for the owner.
        r w x  T : The 2nd octet are permissions for the group.
Owner:  4 2 1  7 : The 3rd octet are permissions for everyone else.
Group:  0 0 0  0 : For each octet, start at 0 and:
Other:  0 0 0  0 :  +4 for read permission.
                 :  +2 for write permission.
                 :  +1 for execute permission.
```

So you need to figure out want permissions you need for the owner,group and others. Add the digits for read, write and execute for owner,group and other.

755 would r,w,x for owner; r,x for group and others.
777 would be r,w,x for all 3.

edit:

If you have problems with locks check if there is a *ldb file (that's the lock file) with permissions lower than 770. If their is check these settings and their values (values and workgroup are arbitrary):

force group = workgroup
force create mode = 0770
force directory mode = 0770
force security mode = 0770
force directory security mode = 0770

Samba will then create the *ldb file with rwxrwx--- and be able to remove the locks.

Comment: client or server?  Can you expand on the values someone should try - especially to the uninitiated...

Comment: values? you meant for the mask: those are standard chmod values.I'll add them in :)

Comment: Only problem solved, now the new problem is. When i paste something to my system from another system. The files are locked totally..

Comment: "locked totally" - what do you mean? Can't the files be copied? Are the files copied, but can't you read its contents?

Comment: @Lekensteyn @khartick87 edited in something about the lockfile. If it doesn't help please comment and I'll check my settings again!

Comment: where these *ldb file will be located ?

Comment: That is a internal database; killing the smbd process **holding the entry** deletes the lock (kill {process}). But this is all done with settings inside smb.conf: if you tell it to recreate as read only samba will copy it as read only. afaik everything you need is in my answer.

Comment: I have set it to 0777 and it is working fine. Thank you :)

Comment: cool @khartick87 Glad it works now.