# Ubuntu Cronjob Samba Permission and restart

Tags: command-line, upgrade, samba, restart

Is it possible in Ubuntu to create a cronjob which does give a certain file 777 permission and restarts the Samba server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script in /usr/local/bin/sambapermissions.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
chmod 777 /some/file/you/want/to/make/writable
service nmbd restart
service smbd restart
```

And now create /etc/cron.d/sambapermissions:

```
5 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/sambapermissions.sh
```

This will run every night 5 minutes after 3am.

But what is it you want to do? Do you want to have a file to be writable over a samba share all the time? Maybe check out "create mask" and "directory mask", explained in detail here:
[Files are read-only after copying over samba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44247/files-are-read-only-after-copying-over-samba/44248#44248)

Comment: I want so to say a loop which does that command like every 3hours

Comment: I guess `* */3 * * * /usr/local/bin/sambapermissions.sh`

Comment: I will try this out htank you guys

Comment: One question what does this command do?
#! /bin/sh

Comment: Can I write this code straight forward?

Comment: It is the shell the script should run under.

Comment: should I move to that path?/usr/local/bin/sambapermissions.sh

Comment: You can change it to wherever you want. I think it is a good location

Comment: So I can write your code straight forward so to say

Comment: thus service nmbd restart
service smbd restart did not work. I read that on should use initctl restart smb to restart samba. Should I change those 2 lines for my?

Comment: Depends on your Ubuntu version, but yeah, simply change it

Comment: I got no permission to create sambapermissions.sh

Comment: Open the editor as root, for example with sudo

Comment: How to do that in command line?

Comment: Ok I created those 2 files, So it should work now right

Comment: If I want to use the cronjob every hour how to I accomplish it and how to calculate the time?

Comment: `0 */1 * * * /usr/local/bin/sambapermissions.sh` Check here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: not */1 * * * * ?

Comment: That would be every minute